# Do I need to unsubscribe or will closing the browser tab will take care of it?

Tags: rxjs

I have a plain JavaScript application that runs in the browser. It has a few subjects to which there are a few subscribers. Do I need to ensure that all subscriptions are completed before the browser is closed? Or will closing or moving to another page take care of the clean up and ensure no memory leaks? I can't seem to find a Yes or No answer or one that is not related to Angular.

Comment: Context is needed. Is this a single page application? Which framework, if any. Code sample of subscription. In terms of closing the browser, yes, memory is cleaned up but you don't want to rely on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser closed -> not an issue, all memory is cleared, you don't need to worry about it

As a best practice ensure all subscribers are unsubscribed.

> Example Scenario -> you have a component defined in `/user/:id` this component has multiple subscribers, but you have not unsubscribed. You move from `user/:id` to `/list` and back to `user/:id` then the subscribers are doubled since you did not unsubscribe them, that will build up and cause your browser to crash due to memory leak!

To handle this we can unsubscribe. I would recommend [`takeUntilDestroyed`](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed) pipe operator, which is auto unsubscribe when the component/service/directive is destroyed!

Of course there are other methods, but this is the gist of the problem.

> Unsubscribe to avoid memory leaks and difficult to find bugs due to unnecessary subscribers!

Comment: Thanks, I guess this was the answer I was looking for. I definitely check for already present subscriptions and unsubscribe them if a subject gets subscribed again.